# Two UITableView in the same class? datasource and delegate

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates

I have two tables in the same class, I need each table contains different data but i have a trouble with the delegate...  How can make each table contains a separate delegate? Thanks, sorry for my English.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1; }

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return [dataTable1 count];
     }

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    CeldaFamilia *cell = (CeldaFamilia *)[aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CeldaFamilia"];




    if (!cell) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CeldaFamilia" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    }

    cell.propTextFamilia.text =[dataTable1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
     }
```

Comment: There is a special reason why these methods have the parameter `tableView`. The main reason is that you can do `if [tableView isEqual:tv1] ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by looking at the `tableView` argument that was passed in.  Example:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (tableView == self.tableView1) {
        return [dataTable1 count];
    } else /* tableView == self.tableView2 */ {
        return [dataTable2 count];
    }
}
```

With this pattern, you need to put `if` statements in all of your `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` methods.

Another way to do it is to make one method that returns the array of data for the table view:

```
- (NSArray *)dataTableForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if (tableView == self.tableView1) {
        return dataTable1;
    } else /* tableView == self.tableView2 */ {
        return dataTable2;
    }
}
```

Then use that function in each of your data source/delegate methods.  Example:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[self dataTableForTableView:tableView] count];
}
```

Your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method might still need to have an `if` statement, depending on what the data looks like for each table.

However, I recommend you **don't use either of those patterns**.  Your code will be better organized and easier to understand if you make a separate data source/delegate for each table view.  You can use two instances of the same class, or you can make two different classes and use one instance of each class, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

If you set the tags of each tableView to different numbers, you can use that to differentiate them.

For example, you can do

```
tableView1.tag = 1;
tableView2.tag = 2;
```

Then in your delegate and dataSource methods, you can do:

```
if (tableView.tag == 1) {
    //first table data
}
else if (tableView.tag == 2) {
    //second table data
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add other class for second table (secondTable) and implement in it data source and delegate table view protocols. And in your view controller, which contains 2 tables in viewDidLoad :
SecondTable *second=[SecondTable alloc] init];
second.delegate=self;
second.datasource=second;

And your second table would be a object of SecondTable class, and first table you do like always.